# Cyanogenmod: customise / protected specific apps

Tags: android, cyanogenmod

We are trying to build a branded firmware for specific Android tablet (Nexus 9). The devices will be used by people waiting for flights / trains / etc and therefore have to be locked down to only allow specific apps to be opened.

Is there any way to restrict specific apps (or password-protected them) from launch? I.e. we can hide Settings app by implementing our custom Launcher, but there are still other ways to launch Settings (i.e. from top drawer). Do we have to modify the source code of Cyanogenmod and rebuild it or there is a cleaner way of configuring such stuff?

Comment: To my knowledge, none of that is "configurable" in Android, including Cyanogen. I don't see how you can do this without making source modifications.

Comment: One possibility to look at is restricted profiles: https://support.google.com/nexus/answer/3175031?vid=1-635809532466899693-3954447106